# Execute external jQuery code without calling an explicit function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I wrote some jQuery code in an external file, with the goal to match each `<select>` tag in the page where the script is included.

My goal would be to include the script reference in the `<head>` tag of the target pages and "run" the jQuery code without having to call any function.

I have seen several examples with external jQuery code, but all call a function to execute the  (external) code.

If I use "plain" javascript, like simple alerts, they are executed without problem. When I try with my jQuery code, nothing happens.

Here is my external jQuery file:

```
$(function() {     
    $("select").focus(function() {
        alert('selected...');
    }).change(function() {
        alert('changed...');  
    })   
});
```

Even if I do not use `$(function(`) at the beginning I always get the exception "Object Expected" at the first occurrence of `$`, while even leaving `$(function()` and inside the brackets a simple alert it works.

How the external file should be developed?

I tested the external script inline in a test page and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no difference *where* your code is written, either inline in your HTML page, or included via `<script src='...'>`.

The issue then would be that jQuery has not yet been included by the time your code is being executed. Take a look at the order which you're including your files, and ensure that jQuery comes before this code which relies upon it.

Comment: Thanks nickf for the suggestion. In the MasterPage the jQuery library  is included in the <head> tag. How can I ensure that it is included on the right time before executing the external code?

Comment: @Luca: just put it after the script tag which includes jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You may be executing the jQuery code before jQuery has been loaded. In that case calls to docready ($(function(){})) would fail because $ !== jQuery yet. Usually to accomplish something like this I would put some code towards the bottom of my file akin to:

```
$(function(){
  var t = "external_file.js",
      s = document.createElement("script"),
      h = document.getElementsByTagName("head");

  s.src = t;
  s.type = "text/javascript"
  h.appendChild( s );
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $("select").focus(function() {
        alert('selected...');
    }).change(function() {
        alert('changed...');  
    })   
});
```